# Unique eigenvector representation without discontinuities

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose a matrix in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has $n$ different real eigenvalues. There are now $n$ eigenvectors that are unique up to a scaling factor. By requiring them to be of unit length, they are unique up to a sign.

Now, I can try to define the first component of the vector to be positive in order to resolve the sign issue. However, not only do I run into problems when said component is zero, it also leads to discontinuities: When the eigenvector is changed by a small amount, the representation can jump to a different value.

Is there a unique representation that resolves this issue? The representation does not necessarily have to be a valid eigenvector itself.

All I can think of  is to use the matrix $\frac{vv^\top}{\|v\|^2}$ to uniquely represent eigenvector $v$, but that isn't very compact as the number of components is squared.

In the special case of $\mathbb{R}^2$ I suppose I can obtain the angle of the vector, and construct a new vector with exactly twice the angle and unit length. Can this be extended to arbitrary dimensions.

Comment: I don't think this is easy. Why don't you accept an implicit sign undeterminacy, i.e. as if the vector was $s\vec v$ where $s=\pm1$ ? There should be no place where this leads you to a dead-end. For example, the cross-product would also have an undeterminate sign. And there are little reasons to add two such vectors...

Comment: @kimchilover Correct, I meant real eigenvalues. Question updated.

Comment: @yvesDaoust I may just have to do that. My issue is that I have to do a lot of comparisions of eigenvectors (how close they are) and the sign issue causes a lot of extra computation. Anyway, knowing there isn't an easy solution is helpful too.

Comment: Pick $V \in \mathbb{R}^n$ uniformly distributed over $[0,1]^n$. With probability 1, $V$ is not orthogonal to any of your $n$ eigenspaces.  For each eigenspace, choose the unique nonzero unit eigenvector that is closest to $V$.

Comment: @Michael Interesting. The response to a small change in the eigenvector direction can still be arbitrarily large, but, as I understand it, the probability of running into that issue decreases with $n$.

Comment: @RichardK.Wade: are you sure that in the comparisons for closeness the signs still matter ?